# Tuple and Int Issue when defining function

Tags: python, int, tuples

Python is giving `TypeError: '>=' not supported between instances of 'tuple' and 'int'.`

I've already tried `spacing`, `bracketing,` and other `syntax errors`.

```
def y(t):
    t = (-9, -6, -3, 0, 3, 6, 9, 12, 15, 18, 21, 24, 27, 30)
    if t>=0:
        return -(3*(len(t**2)+5))
    if t<0:
        return (3*(len(t**2)+5))

print(y(-9))
```

Expecting Python to print answer for `y(-9)`. Python instead gives `TypeError: '>=' not supported between instances of 'tuple' and 'int'.`

Comment: You have `t = -9` coming in as a integer, but before you do the comparison you are overwriting it to be `t = (-9, -6, -3, 0, 3, 6, 9, 12, 15, 18, 21, 24, 27, 30)`, so it isn't `-9` anymore. Now its a tuple containing all those numbers you put it. Think about it, what does `(-9, -6, -3, 0, 3, 6, 9, 12, 15, 18, 21, 24, 27, 30) >= 0` even mean? What exactly is this function supposed to do?

Comment: I'm trying to have Python calculate the value of y(t), and trying to make it decide which equation to use when given a certain value for t that is greater than or lesser than 0.

Comment: Yeah but the problem is by the time you do `if t>=0`, `t` isn't `-9` anymore, because you are overwriting it with a tuple. The problem is this line `t = (-9, -6, -3, 0, 3, 6, 9, 12, 15, 18, 21, 24, 27, 30)`. If you tell me what this is actually calculating I can probably put together an answer for you but as it is I cant really tell what this equation is supposed to represent

Comment: I see what you're saying. How do I have Python run each of those numbers through the "if t>=0..." sequentially and return each answer?

Comment: Let me write it up as an answer real quick, or it would be really hard to read. I think I understand what you are trying to do now. You are trying to feed each value in the tuple into the function, right?

Comment: The thing is that you should almost **always** avoid using the same variable names inside the function body that you accept as formal parameter in the function definition.

Comment: Yes, @DetectivePikachu, exactly

Answer (score 0):

This answer is informed by the comment chain so readers forgive me if it doesn't seem to match up with what is in the question. Read the comment chain on the question to understand why this answer is being provided

So you actually want to feed the values `(-9, -6, -3, 0, 3, 6, 9, 12, 15, 18, 21, 24, 27, 30)` into the function and print the result. So we need to move this out of the function, loop through the tuple and feed each value into the function individually. I've changed the names of the variables to better express their intent. I would recommend doing this in your code always, because it can get quite confusing to figure out what a variable named `t` means, especially if you end up looking at this code again in 2 weeks!

```
def y(value):
    if value>=0:
        return -(3*(value**2)+5)
    if value<0:
        return (3*(value**2)+5)

data = (-9, -6, -3, 0, 3, 6, 9, 12, 15, 18, 21, 24, 27, 30)
for item in data:
    print(y(item))
```

The only thing I'm not sure about is the return statements, because I'm not sure what these are supposed to be calculating. An integer doesn't have a length. If this is actually supposed to be the length of the tuple (meaning this would only output 593, or -593 given this tuple), then you would do this

```
def y(value, length):
    if value>=0:
        return -(3*(length**2)+5)
    if value<0:
        return (3*(length**2)+5)

data = (-9, -6, -3, 0, 3, 6, 9, 12, 15, 18, 21, 24, 27, 30)
for item in data:
    print(y(item, len(data)))
```

I hope this helps. If anything is unclear or if I misunderstood something, comment below and I will fix this answer when I can.

Comment: It worked! The first part of your answer is what I was working for, thanks!